# What is best solution for initialize struct array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

First solution:

```
struct str {
    char *name;
    int flag;
};

enum {
    HELP,
    OUTPUT,
    OTHER
};

typedef struct str table;

table arr[] = {
    { "help", HELP },
    { "output", OUTPUT },
    { NULL, OTHER },
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    table *opt = arr;
    printf("%s\n", (opt+HELP)->name);
    printf("%s\n", (opt+OUTPUT)->name);
    return 0;
}
```

Second solution:

```
struct str {
    char *name;
    int flag;
};

enum {
    HELP,
    OUTPUT,
    OTHER
};

typedef struct str table;
table arr[OTHER];

void start_table() {
    arr[HELP] = (struct str) { "help", HELP };
    arr[OUTPUT] = (struct str) { "output", OUTPUT };
    arr[OTHER] = (struct str) { NULL, OTHER };
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    start_table();
    table *opt = arr;
    printf("%s\n", (opt+HELP)->name);
    printf("%s\n", (opt+OUTPUT)->name);
    return 0;
}
```

What are the best? Second solution change automatically if I add or change any element of the array, but is efficient? Is the best enumerate or using the `#define` preprocessor directive?

Comment: Define `best`..

Comment: They are the same with only difference that the second example not initializes the array but sets the values later. The "dynamic" may mean that the size of array is not fixed but dynamically allocated from free memory.

Comment: Why do you even need that enum? Just have it be an array of `const char *`, since the number is just the index

Comment: `arr[OTHER] =`  write to out of bounds.

Comment: enum is for easy access to array elements and I don't have to edit the array if I change an option or change order, it depends from enum; with #define I have to edit array and the #defined macro manually

Comment: What's the better tool; a hammer or a screw-driver?  This is analogous to your question and is unanswerable - you use the right tool for the job.  For this rather contrived code the first is the least error prone (the second even has a bug as if to prove that point).  "Static" and "Dynamic" do not really characterise either solution; one uses initialisation, the other uses assignment; I am not sure how that can be characterised  as static/dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

It depends!

- When initialization can be used, use it — so the first solution is often better, especially if the code never changes the structure (array) contents.
- If your code can change the contents but might need to be able to reset to the original state, then the initialization function becomes more appropriate and using direct initialization is not appropriate.

There is no one 'best' solution; what is best depends on what you need to do with the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using a C99 specific intializer syntax, you can get the advantages of the second approach in a static initializer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct str {
    const char *name;
    int flag;
};

enum {
    HELP,
    OUTPUT,
    OTHER,
};

typedef struct str table;
table arr[] = {
    [HELP]   = { "help", HELP },
    [OUTPUT] = { "output", OUTPUT },
    [OTHER]  = { NULL, OTHER },
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    table *opt = arr;
    printf("%s\n", opt[HELP].name);
    printf("%s\n", opt[OUTPUT].name);
    return 0;
}
```

The advantage of this technique is it makes no assumption on the order of the enum values, nor on their actual values as long as they are positive, distinct and reasonably small.